# Problem with sql query

Tags: c#, sql

INSERT INTO [Tasks]
               ([LoginName]
               ,[Type]
               ,[Filter]
               ,[Dictionary]
               ,[Description])

```
Select N'Anonymous',4,'SomeTable.targetcode in (select Code from cities where countrycode in ('TN')) and SomeTable.SomeValue in ('13','15')',3,N'Cities from tunis'
Union All
...
```

[Dictionary] is a part of query that i need to function on my server.

I get:

```
Incorrect syntax near ')) and SomeTable.SomeValue in (13,15)'.
```

How to repair this mistake ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have apostrophes within a value. Specifically, your filter string includes apostrophes in it, which need to be escaped by doubling them up:

```
INSERT INTO [Tasks]
       ([LoginName]
       ,[Type]
       ,[Filter]
       ,[Dictionary]
       ,[Description])

Select N'Anonymous',4,'SomeTable.targetcode in (select Code from cities where countrycode in (''TN'')) and SomeTable.SomeValue in (''13'',''15'')',3,N'Cities from tunis'
Union All
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear exactly what you are trying to do, on face value you are trying to insert a part of a where clause into the table.

What is catching you out is the in `('TN')` because the quotes within that part are ending the outer quotes. Try `(''TN'')`